# Формула временной последовательности

Tags: excel

Есть временная последовательность к примеру:

последовательность 7-12 в этой последовательности не может быть интервал 6 и не может быть интервал 13

То есть, четкий диапазон от 7 до 12 и ни каких отклонений! есть числовой ряд 1-2-3.

В этом числовом ряде работает цикличность 5-7-9 не может быть цикличности 1-2-3-4 так же не может быть
цикличности 6-8-10 и тд

Точки пересечений числового ряда 1 или 2 или 3 могут сойтись только в одном единственном месте, где цикличность
5 или 7 или 9 совпадет с временным рядом от 7 до 12, тем самым исключится возможность разброса диапазона 7-12 и
остается конкретный временной интервал который будет равен либо 7, либо 8 либо 9 или 10-11-12. Можно ли это выразить в обычной формуле?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите пример, без него непонятна задача

Comment: [Я случайно создал две учётные записи, как их объединить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: Рисунки - хорошо... А данные где?